# Java Swing with Threads - repaint and two for loops give error with no hint

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, for-loop, repaint

I have a litte java prog which has a two dimensional int-array :     private int[][] blockGrid;
I want to catch the values of the array with two for-loops in a repaint function (which is called periodically as a thread)

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    drawthings(g);
}

private void drawthings(Graphics g) {


    for(int ix=0;ix<20;ix++)
    {
        for(int iy=0;iy<18;iy++)
        {
            System.out.print( blockGrid[(ix)][(iy)] + " ||");
        }
    }
```

When I start the program I get errors, but no syntax highlighting so I'm clueless where the error comes from.

Error messages  are :

```
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at iota_cafe3.Board.drawStar(Board.java:268)
    at iota_cafe3.Board.paintComponent(Board.java:255)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5255)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1643)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1618)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5203)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5013)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:865)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at iota_cafe3.Board.drawStar(Board.java:268)
    at iota_cafe3.Board.paintComponent(Board.java:255)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5255)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1643)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1618)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5203)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5013)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:865)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete stack trace?

Comment: I just added some more lines of error messages

Comment: line 268 is the line i mentioned above : 
System.out.print( blockGrid[(ix)][(iy)] + " ||");
(it has no syntax error...so I assume it has something to do with the thread handling for loops? I'm new to this...obviously)

Comment: Thank you  - I'm getting it a bit -  I do understand that is has something to do with the definition of the array, which is somehow not pointing to a memory address. 

But on a previous line the exact same code is working (which means the array is pointing to a memoryplace IMHO). I also defined the array with 0 on each element with two for loops :

        int[][] blockGrid = new int[21][19];
     for(int ix=0;ix<20;ix++)
     {
      for(int iy=0;iy<18;iy++)
      {
       blockGrid[ix][iy]=0;
      }
     }

So maybe it is has to be static or what is the clue here?

Comment: It works now - i made the definition public static
    public static int[][] blockGrid = new int[21][19];

TY for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if the array `blockGrid` is initialised and in the scope of the drawStar method.
you have null pointer exception in `drawStar` method.
check the methods for calles that may be pointing to null and be sure to catch them (with `try`/`catch` or with `if(x != null)` before the call)

Comment: It works now - i made the definition public static public static int[][] blockGrid = new int[21][19]; TY for your help!!

Comment: no problem, just look on your code and make sure that it is rational to make blockGrid static and not passing it in some way